# PyCharm debugger fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, pydev

I cannot debug a Flask application in PyCharm. The application should run on port 5000: `app.run(host="10.1.0.17", port=5000, debug=True)`. The console output is:

```
C:\Python\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 145.597.11\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 10498 --file "D:/TGM/SMS/SMS/Back .v2/wsgi.py"

pydev debugger: process 4108 is connecting
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 10499

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 145.597.11\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1523, in <module>
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 145.597.11\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 317, in connect
    self.initialize_network(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 145.597.11\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 304, in initialize_network
    self.writer = WriterThread(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 145.597.11\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 392, in __init__
    self.cmdQueue = _queue.Queue()
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I am using Python 3.5.1.  What could be wrong?

Comment: If you have your own `queue.py` file, this will happen

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The pydev debugger uses the same Pythonpath as the project you are trying to debug.
If you have any modules or packages with names of standard modules or packages, the pydev debugger might load your module instead of the standard module.

You probably have a module called `queue` in your projects directories, which causes this issue, since the python standard library also includes a module with that name.

try renaming your module, or changing your PYTHONPATH

PyCharm has the option to not include the projects root/source roots in the PYTHONPATH in `Run > Edit Configurations`. This could fix your problem, although you might need to fix some `import` statements in your project, if any of your `import` statements relied on this setting.

Comment: Yes, I have a file named `queue.py` indeed. I'm not sure if the program works properly now, but why does it run at all? This error comes out only when I debug the project.

Comment: That your program runs is the expected behaviour. The correct question would be WTH does the pydev debugger load your project files... I think the pydev debugger should not do that. It is either an issue with the pydev debugger, or with PyCharm invoking it incorrectly.

Comment: Worked for me!

What I did was:
1> Go to Run/Debug Configurations
2> For the current file, From the 'Configuration', 'Logs' Tab, Select Configuration Tab (Default)
3> Uncheck both 'Add content to PYTHONPATH' and 'Add source to PYTHONPATH'

Hope it works for others having the same issue. Peace