# PyDev debugger not works with Queue.py file

Tags: python, pydev

I started to use PyDev in Eclipse and happen to get a problem when debugging my own file **Queue.py**.

When I started debugger I got error on traceback:

```
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue'
```

I found this related to [PyCharm debugger fails with AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181768/pycharm-debugger-fails-with-attributeerror#) . Though only one part of solution works for me. I clean project **src** folder from **PYTHONPATH**, and I see the traceback not show any errors, but debugger not stops on break points in my **Queue.py**.

Though debugger works fine if I rename file to Queue_1.py

The question is. How to make PyDev debugger works with file named **Queue.py** or any name I choose? I work with training examples, and predict I will have a lot of files with such names conflicts (data structures, algorithms etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a module whose name clashes with the standard library modules.

I.e.: having something as `myproject.Queue` is ok, but just `Queue` is not because you're actually breaking everyone that uses the `Queue` module (including the debugger).

Comment: why this is not the issue with other IDE like VSCode? Is it good practice for debugger to use top level module name, but not store Queue in package? I will try to use your solution with package though, and get back

Comment: Just tried and it seems works. I did a myFolder folder in src and put Queue.py in it. Now debugger works, though the question still open. Should debugger (or any other tool) use top level names?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, all tools should be able to use python/Lib libraries  (otherwise, they'd have to reimplement and create private copies of lots of things that python already has builtin). It's expected that other libraries will not shadow Python builtins (the usual process is creating your own top-level package and putting other things beneath it) -- otherwise, you're probably breaking other stdlib modules as the stdlib itself doesn't expect to be shadowed..